# Third party django rest framework application

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How do we save the versions of all the packages inside a single file using command prompt??

Answer (score 0):

```
C:/ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To check all the versions of packages:

```
C:/ type requirements.txt
```